# Create a mail enabled security group with graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to create a mail enabled security group using the microsoft graph API. Is there a way to do this using the graph api? Thanks a lot.
When we post the following request :
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
{"displayName":"TestWimSecMail","mailEnabled":true,"mailNickname":"TestWimSecMail","securityEnabled":true,"visibility":"Private"}

we get the following response:
{
  "error":
  {
    "code":"Request_BadRequest",
    "message":"The service does not currently support writes of mail-enabled groups. Please ensure that the mail-enablement property is unset and the security-enablement property is set.",
    "innerError":
    {
      "request-id":"a7ebbb39-9390-459d-89ba-7a6e88022cb4",
      "date":"2017-01-03T08:29:38"
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

Creating an email enabled security group is not supported on the API today, you can read them, but not create them. The only mail enabled groups that can be created via Microsoft Graph are Office 365 Groups (aka unified groups).
We do support pure security (non-mail enabled) group creation as indicated on https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_groups.

Please make a request via User Voice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: It is lame. Updating the groups with a [PATCH](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_update) request to change the `mailEnabled` property results in the same error.

Comment: Hit this 4 years later with New-AzureADGroup which incidentally, requires you to pass a mailnickname even when you're not trying to create mailenabled groups.